# Error in fetching image using wp_remote_get() function

Tags: php, wordpress, image

I am using `wp_remote_get` to fetch image from a url and attach it to a post as a Featured Image. I was able to do it initially using some help from [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/40301/how-do-i-set-a-featured-image-thumbnail-by-image-url-when-using-wp-insert-post/41300#41300) post and images were successfully set as featured image and are displaying in backend but now images are set as featured image successfully but only name of image is being displayed (as if the path of image file is broken).

When I go to image path using ftp, I can see image file but when I try to open image it says unsupported format.

Below is the code I used to fetch images

```
$upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();            
$image_url = $one_post->images[0];
$image_data = wp_remote_get($image_url);
//Get image and set unique file name
$filename = $new_post_id."_".$one_post->ID."_".basename($image_url);    
if (wp_mkdir_p($upload_dir['path'])) {
     $file = $upload_dir['path'] . '/' . $filename;
     } else {
       $file = $upload_dir['basedir'] . '/' . $filename;
     }
file_put_contents($file, $image_data);
$wp_filetype = wp_check_filetype($filename, null);
$attachment = array(
           'post_mime_type' => $wp_filetype['type'],
           'post_title' => sanitize_file_name($filename),
           'post_content' => '',
           'post_status' => 'inherit',
      );            
$attach_id = wp_insert_attachment($attachment, $file, $new_post_id);
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');
$attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata($attach_id, $file);
wp_update_attachment_metadata($attach_id, $attach_data);
set_post_thumbnail($new_post_id, $attach_id);
```

If I open image file with a text editor I am seeing something like below

```
ArrayÿØÿà JFIF
```

Is there some error in encoding?
Please Correct me what I am doing wrong.

Comment: `ÿØÿà JFIF` is correct - those are the first bytes of a jpg image.

Comment: I suspect it's going wrong with `file_put_contents(...`, `$image_data` will return an array which is why you're seeing `Array` when you open the image in a text editor. You need to get an element from that array instead. I'd suggest using `media_sideload_image` by the way: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/media_sideload_image

Comment: `ÿØÿà JFIF` are correct but what about the `Array` before it?

Comment: I just removed that `Array` and now I can see image. Any Idea now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment you're seeing this issue because of the way you're using `wp_remote_get()` and `file_put_contents()`.

I also see that you're duplicating some WordPress functionality. In my example below I've rewritten your code to take advantage of existing WordPress functions.

```
$image_url = $one_post->images[0];

$tmp = download_url( $image_url );

// fix filename for query strings
preg_match( '/[^\?]+\.(jpg|jpe|jpeg|gif|png)/i', $image_url, $matches );

$file_array = array(
    'name'     => $new_post_id . '_' . $one_post->ID . '_' . basename( $matches[0] ),
    'tmp_name' => $tmp
);

// Check for download errors
if ( is_wp_error( $tmp ) ) {
    @unlink( $file_array['tmp_name'] );
    return false;
}

$id = media_handle_sideload( $file_array, $new_post_id );

// Check for handle sideload errors.
if ( is_wp_error( $id ) ) {
    @unlink( $file_array['tmp_name'] );
    return false;
}

// Set post thumbnail.
set_post_thumbnail( $new_post_id, $id );
```

Based on the example given on the Codex page for `media_handle_sideload()`: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/media_handle_sideload

Comment: I tried it using `media_sideload_image()` on my own, but failed to set it as featured image, and also I was not able to control image name using `media_sideload_image()` function but your solution is doing both.
Thanks :)